# How to upgrade from 1.8 alpha (1.8.0.0-alpha1) to 1.8 FINAL

Tags: upgrade, installation, magento-1.8, ce-1.8.0.0

I've built a Magento site around 1.8 alpha release.
Now 1.8.0.0 final is out, and I wish to upgrade my installation.

**What would be the easiest path of accomplishing this?**

Please note that my site is not yet in production.

Comment: If you ask me, just copy the new files over and run your tests (haha?) I don' think there are much problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. touch maintenance.flag - Set exception for you IP Address!
2. Make a full backup of both site and database
3. If you can, test your upgrade on your local
4. rsync all the 1.8CE files into your application.- It would help to have GIT or SVN installed so you can track files
5. Run update
6. test - remove flag

Upgrade should take less than one minute

Answer (score 1):

You're good to go with the following shell steps:

Before proceeding with this part of Magento upgrade, it is important to see to what version Magento upgrade scripts will upgrade your store. Enter this command to check this:

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

After that you can upgrade your Magento to Magento 1.8.0.0 stable using this command:

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

If "./mage upgrade-all --force" will not work, you can try to execute this command:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

You will see upgraded packages on your screen. Now the upgrade is complete and you can execute database upgrade visiting your Magento store in your browser, this process will take several minutes, so be patient. If everything was upgraded correctly, you will see upgraded store in your browser. Before database upgrade it is recommended to increase time and memory limits of your PHP engine.

Comment: Will this mess up with my custom modules and template changes?

Comment: Assuming you don't have worked in the core files; no, it should not affect your custom modules and template changes.